# Sourdough starter in hot climate

Tags: sourdough, heat

I live in a hot climate. Days average 85-90 F and nights only get down to 75 F lately. I started a SD starter from scratch 6 days ago. Using the King Arthur recipe found online, and whole wheat grocery store flour. I’ve been keeping 1/2 cup starter, feeding it 1 cup AP flour and 1/2 cup room temp water. The first 3 days it doubled quickly. Now it bubbles some but doesnt seem to rise. Smells very mild/pleasant now. I’ve got it in a glass crock with lid. 
Should it rise more? What can I do to get it to rise?

Comment: Hi @Lily, and welcome to the site! You can edit your question (rather than use comments) by clicking "edit" underneath the question.